# iOS - Override UITextView Methods?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, overriding, uitextview

I want to override the method that draws the text into a UITextView. What is the correct method to override?

Comment: It'd help a lot if you stated the actual problem and what you aim to achieve. This reads like your proposed solution :)

Comment: I am trying to override this method to change the style of the text I am trying to draw. So let's say draw text with multiple colors

Comment: You can draw text with different colors by setting the `textColor` property?

Comment: @David no you can't that allows only 1 style for the whole text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update 2016-02-09:** This answer is now wrong (and has been since iOS 6). You can now use UITextView by setting an NSAttributedString to the `attributedText` property instead of setting a normal NSString to the `text` property.

Relevant newer question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14231900/458205

---

**Original Answer**

There's no way to set different colours for different words in a UITextView.

There are multiple replacements for a UITextView which support rich text editing (listed bellow).
However if you  **only** want to give different text different color's in a UITextView (like syntax highlighting) the easiest thing to do is just use a UITextView itself for the editing with a CoreText overlay displaying the coloured text.

https://github.com/SquaredTiki/EditableCoreTextOverlay

- **EGOTextView** : http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/egotextview
- **BCTextView** : http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/bctextview
- **JTextView** : http://codaset.com/jer/jtextview
- http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=rich+text&commit=Search

Answer (score 1):

Multiple colors in a `UITextView` is not possible at this point in time. You can set one text color only.

If you need multiple text colors, the only way is loading a RTF file in a `UIWebView`, but that doesn't allow editing.

Maybe in iOS 5 there'll be RTF support for `UITextView`.

Comment: that's not correct I've seen libraries that do this, but I want to write my own

Comment: I think you're getting mixed up between the meanings of `library` and `subclass`...? There're some subclasses that can do this to a limited extent on GitHub, but `UITextView` cannot.