# how to show alert with all messages from array

Tags: ios, ipad

I am receiving messages from web service which i saves in NSMutableArray.

if i have 5 messages inside array i need to show all of them within single alert view.

```
NSString *temp; // Here there is only one message, i want to read all message from Array and feed to alert view.

UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info"
                            message: temp
                            delegate:nil
                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this...

```
NSString * temp = [yourArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Note: If you need any joined component like `,` `:` etc, You can modify accordingly. If you want space as joined component, use this `@" "(single space), @"\n"(multiple lines)`

Comment: thank you very much, this shows all messages, is there any way i can differentiate all messages. it shows like paragraph… 1234 some things to diff between 1 2 3 4.

Comment: @user2813740 I think, this is best way to show(1 2 3 4). If you specify format, i'll tell which is either possible or not?

Comment: i mean it just looks like paragraph.. i was wondering if i can do some thing like > or * in front of massages or give colour alternate way…. so that they are more readable.. basically those are notification message to user… hop u got my point.. i understand i have to go for custom may be … but if you have any idea or any sample code...

Comment: @user2813740 I didn't understand about your paragraph style. just show example text(para style). see this post to coloring string. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287386/change-string-color-with-nsattributedstring. Just try with NSAttributedString, it may not work, I didn't try this. Because type of `initWithTitle:....`  vary with `NSAttributedString`.

Answer (score 2):

here is your code

```
NSArray *alertArr = @[@"alert1", @"alert2", @"alert3", @"alert4", @"alert5"];
NSString *temp;
temp = [alertArr componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info"
                                                    message: temp
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
```

Comment: Why not just `temp = [alertArr componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];` ?

Comment: thank for your code deanWombourne