# Attributed String issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS, I am using attributed string in my application. Actually my requirement is
in my string like

```
NSString *stg = @"Hi I am Very Good Boy";
```

here I need to change the Background of each space " " to block colour

Please help me anyone

&regards

Comment: What is "block colour"?

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231879/is-it-possible-to-change-color-of-single-word-in-uitextview-and-uitextfield

Comment: Black color means the space shoule be filled with Black Background colour

Answer (score 0):

Answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287386/change-string-color-with-nsattributedstring) will be helpful. You need to work out the ranges for spaces. One way to do this is to call `rangeOfString:options:range` until you have gone through the entire string. See the [NSString reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:options:range:)

Answer (score 0):

Use this it will helpful for you.

```
        NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:txtField.text];
        NSRange range=[txtField.text rangeOfString:@" "];
        [string addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:range];
        [txtField setAttributedText:string];
```

Comment: if i wrote above code only first space" " from starting point background should be black colour and remaining are not

Comment: That is why you need to use `rangeOfString:options:range:`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that change the space background colour.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mutableString = nil;

//NSString *sampleText = self.lblTest.text;
NSString *sampleText = @"Hi I am Very Good Boy I";
mutableString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:sampleText];

NSString *pattern = @" ";
NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:nil];

//  enumerate matches
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,[sampleText length]);

[expression enumerateMatchesInString:sampleText options:0 range:range usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
 {
     NSRange range = [result rangeAtIndex:0];
     // I am using the NSBackgroundColorAttributeName to change the background of space
     [mutableString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:range];
 }];

[self.lblTest setAttributedText:mutableString];
```