# Highlighting particular text in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

In my application I am displaying a text in my label like this

```
cell.lblUserDetails.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ and %@ other likes your post", [dictionary valueForKey:@"username"], [dictionary valueForKey:@"CuriousCount"]];
```

Here I want to highlight Username and CuriousCount (in red color) and also username and CuriousCount should be clickable.

Comment: try to use NSAttributedString..use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287386/change-string-color-with-nsattributedstring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor redColor];
NSDictionary *attrs = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color };
NSAttributedString *nameStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[dictionary valueForKey:@"username"] attributes:attrs];
NSAttributedString *countStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[dictionary valueForKey:@"CuriousCount"] attributes:attrs];

NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
[string appendAttributedString:nameStr];
[string appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" and "]];
[string appendAttributedString:countStr];
[string appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" other likes your post"]];

cell.lblUserDetails.attributedText = string;
```

Comment: this is giving error (app is getting crashed) because of incompatible pointer types sending nsstring to nsattributedstring