# NSCaseInsensitiveSearch not works in rangeOfCharacterFromSet

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nscharacterset

It seems that `NSCaseInsensitiveSearch` not works in `NSString:rangeOfCharacterFromSet`. Can someone explain why? is it correct behaviour?

```
NSString *string = @"James Bond Always Rocks";    
NSRange range = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"J"] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
NSLog(@"range->%@",NSStringFromRange(range)); //This prints range->{0, 1}

NSString *string = @"James Bond Always Rocks";    
NSRange range = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"j"] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
NSLog(@"range->%@",NSStringFromRange(range)); //This prints range->{2147483647, 0}
```

Comment: Note that you could easily create a character set that contains both lower- and uppercase variants of the characters that you want to search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation: "Options: A mask specifying search options. The following options may be specified by combining them with the C bitwise OR operator: NSAnchoredSearch, NSBackwardsSearch." So it seems like a correct behavior, not sure why only those two options can apply.

Comment: That makes sense (to me). NSCharacterSet uses a bitmap to represent the characters in the set, so that testing for membership is *fast*. A case-insensitive membership test would defeat that purpose.