# How to set color for attributed string of UITextField programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm working on a iOS app with Swift. And I have to implement multiple colors for text in UITextField. So far I know how to set color for different parts of UITextField text and how to concatenate them.
This is the example of that:

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes: [:])
attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                   value: color,
                                   range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.characters.count))
```

But when I press delete button and erase some of the text, and when I start wright again, the new text has the color of the last deleted text. I want default color for every new character, regardless which was the last color (color of text when deleting) for text in UITextField. Can I set color or some attribute of text (new text) in this function?

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

So, when new character has been written it will be in my desired color, black for instance. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Look at this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231879/is-it-possible-to-change-color-of-single-word-in-uitextview-and-uitextfield  You have to specify length for a color type

Comment: This  doesn't help.

Comment: did you try to specify the text length in your code.

Comment: Yes, I just need to be sure that every new character in UITextField will be In default color. No matter in what color is text in UITextField.

Comment: Yes.. thats why I asked for length in the code attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                   value: color,
                                   range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.characters.count))   here you are considering length of whole string..make length change here as you wish

Comment: I can't make it work when I change length.

Comment: Look into the `typingAttributes` property of `UITextField`.

Comment: @rmaddy - Thank you very much! This is just what I needed.
`textField.typingAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.black]`
It works now.